# Remove Redundant Data

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g

These are my two tables

1)Salary_Details

```
SAL_NO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
EMP_NO                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
PAY_MONTH                                 NOT NULL DATE
RECORD_DATE                               NOT NULL DATE
CURRENT_BSAL                              NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
SAL_INCREMENT                             NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
FINAL_BSAL                                NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
DESCRIPTION                                        VARCHAR2(1000)
```

2)Pay_Details

```
PAY_NO                                    NOT NULL NUMBER
EMP_NO                                    NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
EMP_ERN_DDCT_NO                           NOT NULL VARCHAR2(20)
ERN_DDCT_CATNO                            NOT NULL VARCHAR2(10)
ERN_DDCT_CATNAME                          NOT NULL VARCHAR2(1000)
PAY_MONTH                                 NOT NULL DATE
AMOUNT                                    NOT NULL NUMBER(10,2)
EARN_DEDUCT                               NOT NULL CHAR(1)
```

This is my oracle query

```
select s.FINAL_BSAL,
       s.EMP_No,
       p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO,
       p.AMOUNT 
from salary_details s,
       pay_details p
where s.emp_no=p.emp_no 
and s.SAL_NO  IN (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO) 
                  FROM SALARY_DETAILS 
                  group by EMP_NO)
```

and here is the result.(Few rows displayed out of total 41 rows)

[image]

Here I need to remove the replicated data for Final_BSal and EMP_NO.
Can I make a group by on EMP_NO or FINAL_BSAL? If so how?

Comment: Show your desired output.

Comment: Rows 1-7 should be combined to one row. What do you expect to happen with the values they have in ern_ddct_catno and amount?

Comment: Of course rows 1-8 should be combined.Can I display ern_ddct_catno and amount under that combined row? have no idea whether it is possible or not

Answer (score 1):

try below query

select s.EMP_NO,
       s.FINAL_BSAL,
       listagg (p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO, ',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO)ERN_DDCT_CATNO,
       listagg (p.AMOUNT, ',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.AMOUNT)AMOUNT
from salary_details s,pay_details p 
where s.emp_no=p.emp_no 
and s.SAL_NO  IN (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO) FROM SALARY_DETAILS group by EMP_NO) 
group by EMP_NO,FINAL_BSAL
order by s.EMP_No

Comment: what's the error ? try once again .Check if field info provided is correct  as can't see any field named as FINAL_BSAL and sal_no in your structure.

Comment: You need to edit your output as well as it doesn't match with your query output.As no column as FINAL_BSAL in your table but showing in output.

Comment: @Jain .. forgive me 4 this madness.. updated my table

Comment: First you are using both the columns  EMP_NO and FINAL_BSAL from same table i.e. Salary_Details so you don't require a join.       select s.EMP_NO,s.FINAL_BSAL
from salary_details 
where SAL_NO  IN (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO) FROM SALARY_DETAILS group by EMP_NO) 
group by s.EMP_NO,s.FINAL_BSAL
order by s.EMP_No

Comment: But I need to show the relevant  Ern_DDCT_CATNO and AMOUNT as well.

Here is the query I have updated above    ------     

select s.FINAL_BSAL,s.EMP_No,p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO,p.AMOUNT from salary_details s,pay_details p where s.emp_no=p.emp_no and s.SAL_NO  IN (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO) FROM SALARY_DETAILS group by EMP_NO)

Comment: try it with oracle 11 g     Hope this will   help                                      select s.EMP_NO,s.FINAL_BSAL,listagg (p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO, ',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO)ERN_DDCT_CATNO.
listagg (p.AMOUNT, ',')WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY p.AMOUNT)AMOUNT
from salary_details s,pay_details p 
where s.emp_no=p.emp_no 
and s.SAL_NO  IN (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO) FROM SALARY_DETAILS group by EMP_NO) 
group by s.EMP_NO,s.FINAL_BSAL
order by s.EMP_No

Answer (score 1):

You need a correlated subquery, not one with a `GROUP BY`.  Also, learn to use proper explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Simple rule:  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause:

```
select s.FINAL_BSAL, s.EMP_No, p.ERN_DDCT_CATNO, p.AMOUNT
from salary_details s join
     pay_details p 
     on s.emp_no = p.emp_no
where s.SAL_NO = (SELECT MAX(SAL_NO)
                  FROM SALARY_DETAILS s2
                  WHERE s2.EMP_NO = s.EMP_NO
                 );
```

A simpler way to write the query is using `row_number()` or `rank()`, but the above is just a simple modification of your approach.

Comment: Very useful practice.Thanks.
But your query still gives same output as mine.Any way to display Final_Sal and Emp_No  one time and the rest accordingly?

Answer (score 1):

> "Here I need to remove the replicated data for Final_BSal and EMP_NO"

There is no duplicated data.  Each row in the result set is distinct.  Simply, you have multiple rows in PAY_DETAILS for each row in SALARY_DETAILS.  So, two choices:

1. This is the desired result, in which case job done.
2. This is not the desired result.  If so, you need an additional business rule, a filter on PAY_DETAILS to determine which single row to return.

For instance this addition to the WHERE clause would return only PAY_DETAILS records for the previous month:

```
and p.PAY_MONTH = trunc(add_months(sysdate, -1), 'MM')
```

(assuming PAY_MONTH is held as first of the month).

Only you (or your users) can no which explanation is the right one, and which additional business rule(s) you might need to apply.